# Canvas Pixel animations from image source

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a little problem to understand the canvas javascript api. What I would like to do is load two png's in memory, so that I have their byte arrays and do some animation with requestAnimationFrame loop.

But I like to load them without displaying them just in memory and access the bytes for some animation effects.

The question is, how would I do something like that. From my observation I learned that I can get the bytes from a `canvas` via `getImageData`. But this requires a canvas attached to the DOM and a `drawImage` call. Is this correct? Is there a way to load the bytes without painting, or drawing anything?

I would then like to use the putImageData method to draw my animated pixel on the screen...? For example line-by-line or some transition effects...
But first...how can I load an prepare my pixel without displaying them?

Any help, links, pointers would be great! If I am on the wrong path please feel free to correct me...

Answer (score 3):

No, the canvas does not need to be in the DOM for manipulations. You can create a canvas just in JavaScript. This is what they usually call a "backing canvas", and usually used for pre-rendering scenes in some libraries.

Here's a [demo from HTML5Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/), where the video is drawn to an off-DOM canvas (It's somewhere at the last part of the article. Search "backing"). It is then "scraped" of it's pixel data for manipulation before it's spit out to the visible canvas.

Just make sure you have the image loaded before painting it into the canvas.